# Make a call to a external mvc controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know if its possible and how to do the following , i have a basic MVC application (ASP.Net) that i have modified to work for me. Now the application already handles authentication perfectly fine but i need to use this authentication in another app.

Without creating a webservice is it possible for me to make calls to the applications authcontroller , if so how

Comment: Excellent question as I'm wanting to do something similar, call a controller from an included .dll. Looks like the prolific tvanfosson answers this below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly call a controller in another application because it is in a separate AppDomain.  If you just want to reuse the existing code, you could refactor it into a separate assembly (library project), include that assembly in your new application, and just reference it from your logon controller.  If you are trying to do single-sign on, then you may want to look at existing SSO solutions, such as [JA-SIG CAS 2.0](http://www.ja-sig.org/products/cas/).

Answer (score 0):

Authentication is a cross-cutting concern that shouldn't be embedded into a single use case/controller.  AOP afficionados would say it should be encapsulated in an aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa guys slow down , im still beginning MVC and all its related details , the single sign on looks promising  , the reason i dont want to go that route yet or even refactor the code and include it in the second project is because its way too simple a project.

Comment: Cut-n-paste works, too, but refactoring to a common, shared assembly isn't all that hard.  Maybe give some more info on what it is you are really trying to accomplish.